# Vue continue on successful callback

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

I have a Vue app with Vuex dependency. Program logic is that message should be sent after successful Facebook share.

This is the method getting triggered on button click for sending the message:

```
onSubmit() {
    if(this.shouldShowShareModal){
        this.$store.dispatch('openModal', 'SHARE_MODAL');
        return;
    }

    this.$store.dispatch('sendMessage', {
        conversation_id: this.conversationId,
        message        : this.messageText,
        message_type_id: 1
    }).then(() => {
        this.messageText = '';
        this.scrollToBottom();
    });
},
```

`openModal` simply sets the value of the given modal to true, thus `v-if` shows the modal which has the button which upon `share` method triggers a Facebook share:

```
share() {
    var self = this;
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/'
    }, function(){
        self.$store.dispatch('sharedThroughFacebook');
        self.$store.dispatch('closeModal', 'SHARE_MODAL');
    });
}
```

Now the issue I have is how can I continue sending the message after Facebook callback is successful? Currently with `sharedThroughFacebook` I am simply setting the store sharing flag to true, but I am not sure about the best approach for sending the message only after a successful callback? If I push the data to modal, that seems like a dirty solution and that modal should not be aware of message state. On the other hand putting the conversation ID, message, type and text on Vuex store seems like an overhead since this component is the only one using the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can compose your action like this

```
actions: {
  async share ({ dispatch, commit }) {
    await dispatch('sharedThroughFacebook') // wait for `sharedThroughFacebook` to finish
    await dispatch('closeModal') // close the modal before sending the message
    commit('sendMesseage') 
  },
  async sharedThroughFacebook (context, payload) {
     FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/'
    })
 }
}
```

Comment: This is not an issue as I already have a success callback. The issue is triggering (or rather continuing the trigger) for sending messages. Propagating the success down

Comment: then why not return a promise from sharedThroughFacebook action `self.$store.dispatch('sharedThroughFacebook').then() // send message`

Comment: Because the `share` method is in modal (on root), and message data is on message component. Message component has `onSubmit` which triggers opening a modal. If I put a callback there for example, it will return when modal successfully opens...I can't catch a callback from after modal opens and user clicks

Comment: what if you compose your actions using async await

Comment: I can't await for a call that should only happen after click on modal. I can't propagate the promise down to original caller